# how to connect to the sqlite database which is created with java eclipse

Tags: java, sqlite, cmd

I want to check my SQLite database which I create it in my java code. I have downloaded [sqlite3,sqlite3.def,sqlite3.dll], but I don't know the exact place for them!
how can I check my SQLite database and its table with cmd?

Answer (score 0):

You need nothing but the command-line shell (`sqlite3.exe` or `sqlite3`).
Start it with the complete path of the database file:

```
sqlite3 c:\some\where\mydatabase.db
```

If you don't want to use the command line, use one of the many GUI tools, such as SQLite Manager.

Comment: I have sqlite3.exe, the problem is, where should I put the 3 file that I say, because now when I query (.databases) there is not the file which I created in my java code!